# SQL: I have a table with multiple identifiers. If any one identifier matches, I want it to roll up to the same master identifier

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of unique identifier combinations that belong to the same person. Sometimes, a person can sometimes have multiple phone numbers and multiple emails. I would like to add a third column to the table that is a personid. If either the phone or the email matches the phone or email in another row, those rows should have the same personid. To give an example, if this is the table.

| Phone | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 800000000 | hello |
| 777777777 | unique |
| 800000000 | hi |
| 555555555 | hi |

This is the desired output.

| Phone | Email | PersonID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 800000000 | hello | 1 |
| 777777777 | unique | 2 |
| 800000000 | hi | 1 |
| 555555555 | hi | 1 |

If it was a one to many relationship, I would just use rank to give each phone or email a corresponding number. However, that only works one direction. I tried to give each column a unique rank or aggregating values that should be combined into an array, but I am stuck figuring out how to use the values to get the desired output

This is what I started with.

| Phone | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 800000000 | hello |
| 777777777 | unique |
| 800000000 | hi |
| 555555555 | hi |

I tried to get arrays of the values that match in the other column.

| Phone | Email Array |
| --- | --- |
| 800000000 | hello, hi |
| 777777777 | unique |
| 555555555 | hi |

| Email | Phone Array |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 800000000 |
| unique | 777777777 |
| hi | 800000000 , 555555555 |

But I can't figure out how to join them together.

I am specifically using snowflake.

Comment: this is that this recent question is also asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71579142/create-an-associated-matching-id-based-on-multiple-columns-in-the-same-table/71579297#71579297

Comment: You are really asking for disjoint graph, which is slightly more tricky that most people want to write in SQL

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at the other post. I appreciate your help. I wasn’t sure the right term for what I was looking for. :)